# How do i switch a custom implementation of a interface on a condition in http controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a method in my controller which basically is just storing a form to the database. 
My form is very big and it has more than 30-40 fields. 
So i need to store this information in different 3 tables on a condition.

For example :

```
foreach($request->all() as $answer):

    if($answer->employeeType === 1){

    //store data to type_one_table

   } else if($answer->employeeType === 2){

     //store data to type_two_table

   } else if($answer->employeeType === 3){

     //store data to type_two_table

  } else {

    //store data to some_other_table

    }

endforeach;
```

So i was thinking to use some custom `StoreInterface` which will have some `store` method.

and extract above logic to its own implementation.

And then in my Controllers constructor receive that interface instance.

But how i can call which `implementation` do i need for particular condition.

Can i do this a controller ?

Or Should i use different strategy in this case.

please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a general interface like this:

```
interface EmployeeStoreContract
{
    public function saveAnswer();
}
```

Then implement this for all of the different ways you can save the answer, e.g.:

```
class FirstTypeEmployee implements EmployeeStoreContract
{
    public function saveAnswer()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And in your controller to figure out how to save the request data:

```
public function store()
{
    $employeeTypesMap = [
        1 => 'FirstTypeEmployee',
        2 => 'SecondTypeEmployee',
        3 => 'ThirdTypeEmployee',
    ];

    foreach ($request->all() as $answer) {
        $employeeType = $answer->employeeType;

        if (!array_key_exists($employeeType, $employeeTypesMap)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Answer type is not available.');
        }

        $employeeStrategyClass = "App\\Service\\Employee\\{$employeeTypesMap[$employeeType]}";
        $employeeStrategyObject = new $employeeStrategyClass;

        $employeeStrategyObject->saveAnswer($answer);
    }
}
```

Please note the namespace where you have these classes `App\Service\Employee`, could be anything you want. Also feel free to make an abstract class or a trait to reuse some of the functionality of each employee class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could you please explain about last 3 lines? 
where did `new $strategyClass;` come from? and why ` $employeeStrategyObject` this exist if we are not using it here.

Comment: @TrueCode, yeah, my mistake, sorry. So basically you create an instance of the class depending on the type of answer and you call `saveAnswer()` on the object.

Comment: i bit new to OOP but i had a question in this particular example does it make sense to have a `EmployeeStoreContract ` ? 

Here basically we are just switching between 3 classes.

Comment: Sure, the interface `EmployeeStoreContract` is to just makes sure that all of the employee classes form the `$employeeTypesMap` array have the `saveAnswer()` method, so nothing special here really. You can do the same like this `if (method_exists($employeeStrategyObject, 'saveAnswer')) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks. Understood. just wondering how can we do this more `INTERFACE WAY` and get benefit of polymorphism? I mean in this case the we could use a `abstract class` if we want to make sure the method must be implemented.

Comment: Well I don't think interface has  a big role in this, because you need some logic to figure out what kind of class to create, so the only thing I can think of is to bind all the classes to an interface to make sure they have the methods you need. I'll be interested to know if you find some better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. sure. i will explore more on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191233/discussion-between-truecode-and-thefallen).

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches.

I will suggest 2 ways that i would personally use:

***1)*** Create dedicated eloquent models one for each case.

For example:

```
if($answer->employeeType === 1){
     EmployeeOne::create($answer);
}
```

And your eloquent model can look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class EmployeeOne extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'type_one_table';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        // your db field names
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Make sure that the array keys of the array you pass to the create function must match your db fields. I just gave you an example of the first `if` so you can take it from here.

***2)***
Another approach would be to create a model that accepts as a parameter the table name. So based on your `if` you are going to pass the table name you want to insert and the data to be inserted.

```
if($answer->employeeType === 1){
    $this->myModel->insertData($answer,'type_one_table');
}
```

And in your model you are going to have something like:

```
public function insertData($answer,$table){
    $query = DB::table($table)->insertGetId($answer); // returns the id of the new record

    return $query;
}
```

So in every `if-else` statement you just change the table name passing to your model function and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my array keys are more complicated and has nested data which i will store as json. there also need to filter and strip some inputs.. So there gonna be bigger logic(Code)... so i dont want to put all logic in my controller. What other approach i can use?